# TP-Link TL-WA850RE Wi-Fi Range Extender won't work

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.10

I bought this to avoid drivers by using the ethernet port but the stupid thing still doesn't work. The range is fine since I can connect with my phone. When I plug in the cable nothing happens. In the network panel menu item, it has a question mark on it. I've uploaded some photos of what it says. Please keep in mind I am new to ubuntu and don't know how to do anything. I did have D-Link Wi-Fi extender but gave up trying to get it to work.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you get to a admin page if you connect the range extender with cable and put 192.168.0.254 in a browser window?

Comment: I haven’t tried yet, I think there is something wrong with it. I did work with my phone and now it doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem; the wired connection on the extender worked fine with Windows on a dual-boot computer, but it wouldn't work with Ubuntu even though I could get a working wired connection directly from my cable router.
I was able to solve the problem by

-- Setting the IPv4 method to manual

-- Copying the address, netmask and  gateway numbers from the wired settings within the extender configuration (I had to use a second computer connected to the extender to find those settings) and entering them in Ubuntu's wired settings

-- Turning off automatic DNS and entering DNS numbers manually

-- Disabling IPv6.

I'm not sure if all these steps were necessary, but this is what worked for me.

I was using the model TL-WA855RE, which I assume is nearly identical to the model in the original question.

Comment: Worked for 850re too, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As this comment is too long for a comment field, posted as an answer:

As you seem to have tried both a D-Link and a TP-Link Extender you seem to be misunderstanding what a WiFi Range extender does and and how it works:

A WiFi Range Extender works by capturing a WiFi signal and transporting that good signal over to a wired connection.  ***It does not turn a crappy WiFi signal into a good signal!* :-(**

So let's say you have your WiFi router in the basement and on the first floor you still have good WiFi reception but on the second floor you don't.  *Then you have to plug in the WiFi extender on the 1st floor and run a cable to the 2nd floor*.

In this particular use case, you might be better off with a [TL-WPA9610 KIT](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/home-networking/powerline/tl-wpa9610-kit/) which will use your existing electricity wires to transport LAN signals (you need 2: one next to the router to send the LAN signals and one in an electricity socket next to your computer to receive them)

*This also makes this question and answer completely off-topic here as there is absolutely no Ubuntu angle...*

#### Sorry! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The signal is fine, I bought it to avoid buying another wifi dongle only to find out it doesn't work with Linux. Technically it should work, just plug in and attach the ethernet cable. I'm trying some other things to get it to work based on TP-Links suggestions. Out of curiosity, the product your suggesting would be faster than Wifi?

Comment: Yes, maximum rate is 300Mbps instead of 45Mbps. (*Both are maxima!*)

Comment: I gave up on this product and returned it. It was not as advertised or at least not what the store told me it would do.

Comment: Like I said: what you need is 2 powerline adapters: One in a socket next to the router and then one next to wherever you need your laptop.  I live in Germany and a good local product is *Fritz!* and they sell them as kits with both Ethernet and WiFi for ~50€